# Oracle not accepting dates before 2000

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, oledb, ora-01858

I'm doing an insert from a C# .NET app into an Oracle database.  The query that is failing looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO staging (create_date) VALUES ('16-Nov-1999')
```

When I run it from SQL Navigator, it runs fine.  Through .NET, the database throws:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

I ran a few test cases and confirmed that it's the year causing the exception.  Anything after '31-Dec-1999' runs fine.

Comment: Does it still fail if you use `to_date('16-Nov-1999', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` as the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better to use the [TO_DATE function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) when submitting values that are to be stored as DATEs:

```
INSERT INTO staging 
   (create_date) 
VALUES 
   (TO_DATE('16-Nov-1999', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

Comment: I considered it, but since this is a dynamically generated statement, I'd have to catch dates as they come in, rather than preformatting the string into the oracle default.  Let me set up a test with to_date(), and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @user480670: if you're preformatting the string you're assuming the date format. The problem is the client date format (`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`) is different to what you're assuming, and you may not be able to control it out in the wild. It's safer not to assume. You can check the format being applied by each client by querying the `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` table.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to refactor to trap dates. What I'm being passed is an array of objects with a fieldname and a value. Each fieldname is assumed to be a column in my table, and each value is guaranteed to be in the correct form for that column.  All I'm really doing is packing them into comma delimited strings and parameters for insert.  I'd appreciate it if someone could tell my why the query is failing.  Otherwise I have to test each value in the array to see if it's a valid date. (and hopefully avoid converting values that aren't)

Comment: @Alex Poole:  Thanks, the server's date format is 'DD-Mon-RRRR' which half explains why dates before 2000 are failing.

Comment: @user480670: Sorry I'm late, but Alex explained the situation.  Because of behavior like this -- I never trust implicit string to date conversion on any database.

Comment: If you're confident the values passed in the objects will be in the right format, you might - depending on how you're connecting I think - be able to set your session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, either as an attribute/parameter of the connection, or with an explicit `ALTER SESSION` statement. To me it looks like your connection is defaulting to some other format. It'd be mildly interesting to know what that is, but you should look at overriding it if that's appropriate for your application. It is generally a bit risky though, so make sure it's right for you in this specific case, otherwise go with OMG.

Comment: I did the refactoring to TO_DATE() and it's working fine.  Thank's for the help.  I looked into the RRRR date format a little more. RRRR - Accepts a 2-digit year and returns a 4-digit year.  A value between 0-49 will return a 20xx year.  A value between 50-99 will return a 19xx year. 

It looks like the fact that it was accepting 4 digit years at all was just a fluke.  .NET just wasn't being consistant.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with using the generic System.Data.OleDB provider.  The Oracle specific System.Data.OracleClient does not have this issue.